# Faced an error during upgrading Magento version from 2.3.5 to 2.4.0

Tags: magento2.3.5, magento2.4

I'm going to upgrade Magento version 2.3.5 to  2.4.0 and getting below error.
Please suggest if anyone has faced the same error.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Is your miravist component up to date? Miravist enhances the elastic search module and for this topic, Magento includes some key changes from MG 2.3->2.4. Othervise you should make an support request for your Miravist component.

Comment: Yes, Mirasvit component is up to date. I just removed that module from composer.json file and tried again and it allows me to upgrade the Magento version. So, I think there is an issue with Mirasvit extension

Answer (score 0):

I've just contacted to Miravit support team and found that they've changed the composer package name for elastic search module. So, I've just replaced it and it allows me to proceed ahead to upgrade Magento version.

Thanks.